# Metal: GPU capture from a unit test

Tags: ios, metal

Is there a way to do a GPU capture from a unit test? This would be useful for our debugging of compute kernels (specifically, how they modify textures). Also useful for profiling and optimization.

I tried using `MTLCaptureManager` but it didn't seem to do anything within a unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in a slightly roundabout way using the programmatic GPU capture APIs introduced in macOS Catalina. Although you cannot perform a capture and automatically launch the Metal frame debugger, you *can* capture inside a unit test and write the results to a GPU trace file for subsequent inspection.

To do this you need to create a `GPUCaptureDescriptor` object specifying which object's scope to capture (device, command queue, etc.), set its destination to `.gpuTraceDocument`, and give it a URL to write the file to. Then you can start/stop capture in your setUp/tearDown methods, or wherever you prefer.

```
let captureDescriptor = MTLCaptureDescriptor()
captureDescriptor.captureObject = commandQueue
captureDescriptor.destination = .gpuTraceDocument
captureDescriptor.outputURL = URL(filePath: "/some/path/someName.gputrace")
try MTLCaptureManager.shared().startCapture(with: captureDescriptor)
```

Note that the host app must have GPU capture enabled either via an environment variable or by adding an entry for the `MetalCaptureEnabled` key (set to a Boolean value of YES) in its Info.plist, or capture will not be enabled, even if it would otherwise be enabled by the app's scheme settings.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented an example project that includes Metal regression xctests. Having the tests really made it easier to develop Metal shaders because you can define test cases and capture the byte or BGRA output of shaders and compare to known good values at a fixed texture size. The project is a test implementation of parallel prefix sum using 2D textures.

[MetalPrefixSum on github](https://github.com/mdejong/MetalPrefixSum)

Comment: That's cool, but doesn't seem to answer my question. Were you able to get GPU capture to work from within a regression test?